# Recovering Lost Brave Browser Usernames and Passwords

Tags: web-browser, password-management, windows-10

I recently changed my password for my local Windows 10 account and found out that my usernames/passwords in Brave's password manager are no longer visible.

Unfortunately, I executed Brave after the password change and I'm told that this changed the encryption key.

Is there anything I can do to get my usernames/passwords back or is this a lost cause?